# std::fill_n on array of non-PODs possible for first initializing?

Tags: c++, fill, initialization

is it possible to use `std::fill` to initialize an array of non-POD types?

The documentation says that `std::fill` uses `operator=` to initialize the array not placement copy construction. The assignment operator, however, does not really have a chance to free any current memory when it is called on an uninitialized space, as far as I can see.

Example:

```
struct NonPod
{
    std::string myStr;
};

NonPod arr[10];
NonPod prototype;
NonPod * ptr = &arr[0];
std::fill_n(ptr, 10, prototype);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't declare `arr` as `NonPod arr[10];` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::uninitialized_fill_n`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/uninitialized_fill_n/) from the `memory` header, not `std::fill_n` from the `algorithm` header.

Beware, however! Your code does not take alignment or padding into consideration -- consider using `std::alignment_of`, or the suitable boost replacement on platforms where it isn't available.